# Get original dataframe from pivoted dataframe with multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a dataframe in a long form like this

```py
data = {'name': ["A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C"],
        'time':["1pm","1pm","1pm","2pm","2pm","2pm","3pm","3pm","3pm"],
        'idx': [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3], 'var1':[34,234,645,3,23,65,34,24,25], 
        'var2':[1,35,2,65,2,1,7,3,8]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image]

I pivot it:

```py
df_piv = df.pivot_table(values=['var1','var2'],index=['name','time'], columns='idx',aggfunc=np.sum)
```

[image]

After I performed some operations on the data in the pivoted dataframe I would like to get it back into the long form.
How would i do that?

I tried several pandas functions including `melt`, `to_records`,`reset_index`, `swaplevel` in multiple combinations. None of it had the desired outcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = df_piv.stack().reset_index()
print (df)
  name time  idx  var1  var2
0    A  1pm    1    34     1
1    A  1pm    2   234    35
2    A  1pm    3   645     2
3    B  2pm    1     3    65
4    B  2pm    2    23     2
5    B  2pm    3    65     1
6    C  3pm    1    34     7
7    C  3pm    2    24     3
8    C  3pm    3    25     8
```

Comment: It could have been so easy. Thank you a lot!